# Analysis services Filter function implicitly filters empty elements

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to filter members from [__Account.Account selection] by some condition regardless if members are empty or not, but Filter() function implicitly excludes empty members. Is this is a bug or a feature? MSDN does not mention such behavior for Filter function.

Any idea how to avoid the issue?

```
WITH 
  SET [__Account.Account selection] AS 
    '{
      {
        [Account].[Account Number].&[110]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[1130]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[1164]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[1210]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[1300]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[20]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[8500]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[8040]
      }
    }' 
  SET [__Account.Account Number_RootMembers_Smart] AS 
    '{
    Filter(
        [__Account.Account selection],
        1 = 1)}' 
SELECT 
  [__Account.Account Number_RootMembers_Smart] ON ROWS
 ,{} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

NOTE: Function Generate() has the same behavior.

NOTE2: By "empty member" I mean member with not value on any measure.

[image: Response]

And there are members with measures...
[image]

Comment: What do you mean that a member is empty? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Member has no values on all measures.

Comment: What client tool is running this query? SSMS MDX window? SSRS? Custom app? Are all rows disappearing or just the empty member rows?

Comment: From 8 specified members two will be in the result as they are ones having the values...

Comment: And if you remove the filter function all 8 return in the query results?

Comment: Yes they are there. The same applies for Generate function...

Comment: If you remove `DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME` what happens?

Comment: Nothing, still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
WITH 
  SET [__Account.Account selection] AS 
    {
      {
        [Account].[Account Number].&[110]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[1130]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[1164]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[1210]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[1300]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[20]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[8500]
       ,[Account].[Account Number].&[8040]
      }
      * [Account].[Account].[Account].Members
    } 
  SET [__Account.Account Number_RootMembers_Smart] AS 
    {
    Filter(
        [__Account.Account selection],
        1=1)}
SELECT  {} ON COLUMNS,

  [__Account.Account Number_RootMembers_Smart] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Notice that I added the `[Account].[Account].[Account].Members` into the query. Previously since it was not mentioned, the current coordinate was the `[All Accounts]` member. Since the Account dimension is a parent-child dimension, the All member doesn't exist with 6 of 8 account numbers apparently. Changing the query ensures that the relevant Account and Account Number pair get put together so that all 8 rows exist in the cube space and show up.

Comment: Returns the same two members with "1" values under HasValue column. Not working :( It works for you? If you have AdwentureWorks (sample database for ssas, you can try)

Comment: Thanks for help btw!

Comment: @Divisadero will try tomorrow. What version of SSAS?

Comment: Version 12.0.2000.8.

Comment: @Divisadero that's 2014 RTM

Comment: @Divisadero I updated my answer. Figured out what was going on.

Comment: What is [Account].[Account].[Account]? I cannot find it in the structure, hence know that it is there...

Comment: @Divisadero it is the parent-child hierarchy